# A transparent optional agrument macro

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

Is there a way to define a macro that takes one optional argument and behaves transparently? The traditional Latex way (`\newcommand{\foo}[1][]{foo}`) has the following shortcome: writing `$T_\foo$` results in error (missing `{` inserted), but doing the same with zero-argument macro is possible.

I think a macro with an optional argument should behave the same way as a zero-argument macro when the argument is not provided. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: you get no error from `{\foo}` if defined as you show.

Comment: If you say `\newcommand{\foo}[1][]{}`, I don't think `{\foo}` will raise an error. Actually, I even tried it, thought I knew it wouldn't. Please, add an example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I have changed the example.

Comment: @egreg: Sorry, I have chagned the example.

Comment: @user87690 That hs nothing to do with the argument but with how does `_` work in math mode.

Comment: @Manuel: But with zero-argument macro it works.

Comment: @user87690 it only works if you define "work" in a rather strange way, if `\foo` has no arguments then `T_\foo` and `T_{\foo}` are completely different things, What becomes the subscript depends on the definition of `\foo` or it could be an error.

Comment: try `$T_\longrightarrow$` for example. `\longrightarrow` has no arguments but only works as `T_{\longrightarrow}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unlike a macro argument, a `_` does not pick up the next token if it is not braced, it *expands*  to find the next non expandable token or brace group

so after

```
\newcommand\foo{abc}
```

then

```
    \fbox\foo
```

is

```
\fbox{\foo}
```

and boxes abc but

```
$T_\foo$
```

is

```
$T_abc$
```

which is

```
$T_{a}bc
```

so omitting the braces is in any case bad style and leads to unexpected behaviour, revealing the internal implementation of `\foo`

With the optional argument version, the behaviour reveals the implementation (and this fails)

If you really want this you can add a group in the definition:

[image]

```
 \documentclass{article}

\def\foo{\bgroup\xfoo}
\newcommand\xfoo[1][]{abc#1\egroup}
\begin{document}



$T_\foo$ $T_\foo[d]$


\end{document}
```

But it is encouraging bad document markup.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think, that writing $T_\foo$ is a bad markup even for zero-argument macros? So one should always write braces: $T_{\alpha}$?

Comment: @user87690 Yes it is bad and it's not related to the argument structure compare with this 0-argument macro `T_\longrightarrow`  and `T_{\longrightarrow}`

Comment: I see. In my situation the macro was just a shortcut for something constant. And when the constant had more tokens, it was enclosed in a group in the definition. But then I wanted to parametrize it, and combining a group in a definition with optional argument is non-trivial (the two step definition with \bgroup). It looks strange to me to write say $T_{0}$ and $T_{\alpha}$ was similar.

Comment: @user87690 note the extra group only works if you want the definition to be an ordinary symbol, `\longrightarrow` has to have a definition `\mathrel{...}` so can not have an outer group or it would lose the relation spacing, which is why `T_\longrightarrow` fails as it is `T_{\mathrel}`